# Pass selected item data from ListView from current activity to next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

I have a Custom ListView of products. Each row of listview contains product name, image, price and description. I want to send the listview's selected item's title, price, description and image be passed from current ListView activity to next activity where it is to be displayed. How do I pass data of selected list item in intent?

This is part of code from my java file which displays the list:

```
private ArrayList<ThemeTourModel> GetThemeTourResults(){
        ArrayList<ThemeTourModel> results = new ArrayList<ThemeTourModel>();

        ThemeTourModel item_details = new ThemeTourModel();
        item_details.settourname("Solo Woman Travellers");
        item_details.settourDescription("Women searching the ultimate liberation may discover it in exploring the tourist destinations of world on their own. More freedom and security while traveling for leisurely getaways and adventures.");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        item_details.setPrice("Rs.6999 - Rs.8999");
        results.add(item_details);
    return results;
    }

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(position==0){
            Intent i0 = new Intent(this,EnquireActivity.class);
            startActivity(i0);
        }
```

Comment: `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra( "ThemeTourModel", ThemeTourModel);`

Comment: can u plz replace my code with ur suggested one because i m not getting it that where to perform changes..

Answer (score 0):

You can put the primitive data through the Intent to another activity by `intent.putExtra(name,value)` and get the values through `getIntent().getExtra()` on the another Activity. You can find the reference here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)
The other way is to let your item object implement `Parcelable` to exchange between activities, check this out: [Android: How to implement Parcelable to my objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854791/android-how-to-implement-parcelable-to-my-objects).

Hope this helps