# Extending a class that implements Parcelable

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a class, we'll call it class A, that implements Parcelable.

I have a second class, we'll call it class B, that extends class A.

My question is:

How do I write class B's member variables to the Parcel and then write it's parent class's (ie: class A's) member variables to the Parcel (and, subsequently, read them in)?

Is there some nifty trick to not needing to rewrite class A's Parcel code?  Or do I just need to rewrite the Parcel code in class A and add additional code for class B's member variables?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> How do I write class B's member variables to the Parcel and then write it's parent class's (ie: class A's) member variables to the Parcel

Class B overrides `writeToParcel()` from Class A, chaining to the superclass and also adding its own objects to the `Parcel`.

> (and, subsequently, read them in)?

Class B implements `public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR` in such a way that it can let both classes read their stuff in. If you take the approach of creating a constructor on Class B that takes a `Parcel` as a constructor parameter, just chain to the superclass constructor (to let Class A do its work), then read Class B's data.

The key will be to do them both in the same order. If you intend to let Class A read its data first, Class A must write its data first.

> Is there some nifty trick to not needing to rewrite class A's Parcel code?

Inheritance and chaining to the superclass.

Comment: How do I call the superclass's constructor?

Comment: @Andrew: The same way you do in any Java class: `super(...)` (where `...` is your list of parameters, if any) as the first line in your own constructor.

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok so i've added the super(parcel); line in my Class B Constructor; how do I now ensure I call the superclass in writing to the parcel?

Comment: @Jethro: Call `super.writeToParcel()` in the subclass' `writeToParcel()` method.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the advice! Put me in the right direction :D

Answer (score 4):

Adding an example, the marked answer is indeed correct, but something more visual seems more suitable for this situation:

This would be the supper class:

```
public class BasePojo implements Parcelable {

    private String something;

    //what ever other constructor

    //getters and setters

    protected BasePojo(Parcel in) {
        something = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<BasePojo> CREATOR = new Creator<BasePojo>() {
        @Override
        public BasePojo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new BasePojo(in);
        }

        @Override
        public BasePojo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new BasePojo[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(something);
    }

}
```

And then this would be the child class:

```
public class ChildPojo extends BasePojo implements Parcelable {

    private int somethingElse;

    //what ever other constructor

    //getters and setters

    protected ChildPojo(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        somethingElse = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<ChildPojo> CREATOR = new Creator<ChildPojo>() {
        @Override
        public ChildPojo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new ChildPojo(in);
        }

        @Override
        public ChildPojo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ChildPojo[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        super.writeToParcel(parcel, i);
        parcel.writeInt(somethingElse);
    }

}
```

The marked answer provides a very good explanation, calling super is the key.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little complex, but the trick is to use [Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful) to get the types of subclass's members and to sort the members so that you can read and write the data back in the same exact order using the proper types.

I have implemented the solution for class A here: https://github.com/awadalaa/Android-Global-Parcelable

so now you can make any class parcelable by simply extending this class.

Comment: Parcelable concept has been introduced in Android to avoid reflection during the serialization. If you are going to reflection then you can simply implement Serializable marker interface.