# Extending an Android Parcelable class

Tags: android, oop, interface, subclass, parcelable

I have a `CustomAddress` class that extends the `android.location.Address` class that implements `Parcelable`.

I am trying to make my `CustomAddress`implement `Parcelable`to but am stuck when creating my class from a parcel. What I want to when creating `CustomAddress`from a parcel is first fill in all the fields from the super class `Address`and then my own fields. So I have implemented the `CREATOR`field:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<CustomAddress> CREATOR
= new Parcelable.Creator<CustomAddress>() {
    public CustomAddress createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CustomAddress(in);
    }

    public CustomAddress[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CustomAddress[size];
    }
};
```

But in my `CustomAddress(Parcel in)`creator, I can't call `super(in)`because it doesn't exist in `android.location.Address`. I can only access `android.location.Address.CREATOR`. So how do I fill in my fields using `CREATOR`?

EDIT: link to the android `Address` class https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question and Mark Murphy's excellent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10841502/1140682

So, in your case, you would make `CustomAddress` extend `Address` (as you already do), call the `super()` method in the constructor and then read your own attributes from the passed `Parcel`. Same has to be done (in same order) in the `writeToParcel()` method, of course here adding your attributes to the parcel.

Comment: Thanks I checked this answer but I think my case is different. If I just call super(), how does the super class now about the Parcel? I want all the superclass fields to be filled up as well.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand that the `Address` class is different because it it doesn't take its parcel from the constructor parameter, instead uses a creator. In this case see no other way than either adapt the code from the `Address.CREATOR`s [`createFromParcel()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/location/java/android/location/Address.java#L477) or use composition instead of inheritance (i.e. let your `CustomAddress` manage an `Address` instead of subclassing it). I understand that both methods would not be best practice.