# Android - polymorphism and Parcelable

Tags: java, android, polymorphism, parcelable

I can't figure out how to use polymorohism when writing/reading from parcel. 
I understand that I need to implement Parcelable in base class, and also in all derived classes (in the case that subclasses have additional properties that I would want to write into parcel). 
What I don't understand and what I don't know if it's even possible is - how to read subclass from Parcelable i.e., how do I know what kind of subclass I am reading from parcel. 
I can do some hack like writing some indicator into parcel that would tell me what class loader to use, but I thought there would be some more elegant way, otherwise there is no much use of polymorphism.

To illustrate my question, let say I have classes like this:

Shape.class

```
public class Shape implements Parcelable {
public float area;

public Shape() {
}

public Shape(Parcel in) {
    area = in.readFloat();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeFloat(area);
    }
//CREATOR etc..
}
```

RectangleShape.class

```
 public class RectangleShape extends Shape {

    float a;
    float b;

    public RectangleShape(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        a = in.readFloat();
        b = in.readFloat();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeFloat(area);
        dest.writeFloat(a);
        dest.writeFloat(b);
    }

//CREATOR etc..
}
```

CircleShape.class

```
public static class CircleShape extends Shape {
        float r;

    public CircleShape(Parcel in) {
        super(in);
        r = in.readFloat();
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeFloat(area);
        dest.writeFloat(r);
    }
//CREATOR etc..
 }
```

Now, in some other class I have something like this:

```
 public  class Geometry implements Parcelable {

    Shape myShape; 

    public Geometry (boolean condition) {

        if (condition) 
            myShape = new CircleShape(4.5);
        else
            myShape = new RectangleShape(3.4, 3.5);
    }


    @Override
    public Geometry(Parcel in) {
        in.readParcelable(??? - **how do I know what class loader to put here?** )
     }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(myShape,flags);
    }
//CREATOR etc..
}
```

Is there any way that i can "tell" android when writing into parcel what subclass it is, without implicit check of instance type?

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my case, the base class was an interface, which made things easier. I think what I did to solve it was to extend `Parcelable` in the interface (let's call it `Foo`), and then I implemented `Foo` in its subclasses, therefore also implementing `Parcelable`. I'm not sure if that helps much...

Comment: I've never implemented parcelable extending other, but I guess a good suggestion would be to check how Google themselves do it. AbsSavedState is a Parcelable class with several subclasses. Here is the source code for it https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/AbsSavedState.java and here for View.BaseSavedState https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#22556

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this little fragment and loaded it into a `FrameLayout` in the main activity to check - and I got positive results (the rebuilt object from the parcel was of type `DerivedClass` although the references of the object were all of type `ObjectClass`).

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    public ObjectClass obj;

    public static final String OBJECT_KEY = "Object key";

    public static Fragment2 newInstance(){
        Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        ObjectClass obj = new DerivedClass(); //a DerivedClass object
                               //referenced by an ObjectClass reference
        args.putParcelable(OBJECT_KEY, obj);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main2, container, false);
        if (savedInstanceState == null){
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            obj = args.getParcelable(OBJECT_KEY); //without supplying the ClassLoader
            ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.section_label)).setText(obj.getTitle()); 
                     //The text that is displayed is: "Child class"!
        }
        return view;
    }

    //The parent class
    public static class ObjectClass implements Parcelable {
        String title = "Parent class";

        public String getTitle(){
            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        }

        public static final Creator<ObjectClass> CREATOR = new Creator<ObjectClass>() {
            @Override
            public ObjectClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new ObjectClass();
            }

            @Override
            public ObjectClass[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ObjectClass[size];
            }
        };
    }

    //The child class
    public static class DerivedClass extends ObjectClass {
        String title2 = "Child class";

        public String getTitle() {
            return title2;
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<DerivedClass> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<DerivedClass>() {
            @Override
            public DerivedClass createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new DerivedClass();
            }

            @Override
            public DerivedClass[] newArray(int size) {
                return new DerivedClass[size];
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And in the main activity, in `onCreate(Bundle)` method:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer, Fragment2.newInstance()).commit();
```

**My thoughts that led me to this check:** As android must figure out what class to use when recreating the object from the parcel (which `CREATOR` to use), I figured it must store this additional information together with the specified information ( specified in the `writeToParcel(Parcel, int)` method) when putting it into the bundle. To determine this class I thought it can either use the reference's type or use the object itself (e.g. using `getClass()` on it). If it uses the object type itself that of course means polymorphism is possible. From my check above it looks like that is indeed the case.

**Conclusion and a guess for your example:**
I think for your example, try not to explicitly pass the ClassLoader. Pass `null`. From the documentation for the parameter of `Parcel#readParcelable(ClassLoader)`:

> ClassLoader: A ClassLoader from which to instantiate the Parcelable object, or null for the default class loader.

I didn't try it with your configuration, so I'm not sure it will work in the same way as in my example. Specifically, I'm not sure whether `Parcel#readParcelable(ClassLoader=null)` actually works in the same manner as `Bundle#getParcelable(String)`. but if my rationale is right - it should (I assume `Bundle#getParcelable(String)` uses the default ClassLoader as long as `Bundle#setClassLoader(ClassLoader)` wasn't called).

Please comment and let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, I have solved this in the same way months ago, just didn't wrote the answer, so will now accept yours.